# Color map on unit sphere when data does not fall on a cartesian grid

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a set of data point triples: (e,a,d) where e is the latitude, a is the longitude, and d is an associated value for this point. The values of (e,a) do not fall on a Cartesian-style grid.  We may think of these coordinates as random.

I would like to plot this information as a heatmap/colormap on the surface of a sphere using Matlab.

Previously, when my data did fall on a Cartesian-style grid, I used [this function from the file exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36665-spheresurf).  Ideally, I'd like to have something like this for my data coming from random points on the unit sphere.

I could modify the approach used in that function by creating a grid that contains whatever values of (e,a) come from my random data, but this is going to be problematic because I do not have a value of (d) for all combinations of (e,a).

Is there a better way to accomplish this plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to plotting and keeping the linked function above is to interpolate the data so that it does fall on a grid.  This is just an option to visualize what the data represents.  This can be accomplished with [the builtin griddata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html).